# Retrieve post thumbnails

Tags: plugins, posts, categories, images, post-thumbnails

I am trying to build a wordpress blog from scratch. I am looking to retrieve all the articles from a specific category. I then want to also include the SQUARE thumbnail(not a stretched version, a cropped square). I am slightly confused on how to do this. I tried searching the web.

```
        <h3>Latest free recipe</h3>
<?php $temp_query = $wp_query; ?>
<?php query_posts('category_name=recipes&amp;showposts=1'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
<div class="meta">
By <?php the_author() ?>
</div>
<div class="storycontent">
<?php 


if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
  the_post_thumbnail();
}else{

}

?>
<?php the_content(); ?>


</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Ron's WordPress Answers Template
*/
include_once('header.php');
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'  => 5,
    'offset'          => 0,
    'category'        => '',//you have to use the category id # here not the name of the cat
    'orderby'         => 'post_date',
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    'post_type'       => 'post',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true );
$posts = get_posts( $args );
global $post;
foreach( $posts as $post ){ 
setup_postdata($post); 
?>
<div class="post">
<p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
<div class="meta">
By <?php the_author() ?>
</div>
<div class="storycontent">
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
  the_post_thumbnail();
}else{

} 
?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php 
       }
include_once('footer.php');  ?>
```

> the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');       // Thumbnail (default 150px x
>   150px max) the_post_thumbnail('medium');          // Medium resolution
>   (default 300px x 300px max) the_post_thumbnail('large');           //
>   Large resolution (default 640px x 640px max)
>   the_post_thumbnail('full');            // Full resolution (original
>   size uploaded)

I like to use ccs like this to make sure the images display "nicely".

```
.storycontent img{
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

Comment: should there be a php open tag at the top

Comment: it says no posts found however i just had them populating but the incorrect size

Comment: i update it, works on my test site.

Comment: how do i put it in my html

Comment: It has to be used as a page template like recipes.php or something to that effect.

Comment: can you please explain I currently have an html file that i just need to display the wordpress posts in.

Comment: You can not display information from word press in a html page, the page has to be a php page. WordPress has to use php to fetch the information from the database and then display it. You can use html in the display of the information but it has to be on php page thats managed via wordpress.

Comment: Take the code i pasted above, save it in a file and save it as a .php file with any name. Then in WordPress go to new page, and on the right side of the page there is a drop down labeled page template. Select Ron's WordPress Answers Template and then click publish.

Comment: the thing is i have a static page in html that i am just using wordpress for the news data. there is no way it can be all wordpress bc of how it is laid out. So how do i just use it as a template for the post?

Comment: my bad its an html page that i converted to php